# Bottom Navigation Menu with Fragment activity for each

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer, bottomnavigationview

Project visual structure: [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bRrs.png)

**Question:** I want to know how to merge fragment activity to one of my buttons on bottom navigation drawer "Dashboard" for example. I don't want to create new android activity and using "Intent" to pass data. I would rather want to have a fragment so that toolbar and bottom navigation drawer should not get changed when clicked to "Dashboard"

Comment: Use a layout viewgroup as a container for fragments in your activity, and then, add or replace fragments in that container. What have you tried?

Comment: Can you please a little bit explain how to do that. I am totally lost in finding effective ways in doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose following is your activity layout:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here, `FrameLayout` with id `fragment_container` is your fragment container. All the fragments will be loaded into this container.

Then, in your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` method, set this layout as contentView using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Get an instance of our container element,

```
FrameLayout fragmentContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
```

Now, when you need to change fragment, call this method (placed in `MainActivity`):

```
public void changeFragment (Fragment fragment, String fragmentName) {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(fragmentContainer, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentName);
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

If you are using support fragments from support library, use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`